How can I view a video at 10 to 100 times higher frame rate?
I have recorded long videos of slow phenomena at frame rates of 1 frame per second down to 1 frame per minute and even slower.
Now I would like to play these boring videos at higher frame rate of, say, 10 to 100 times faster but without losing a single frame.
My video players (mplayer, VLC etc.) seem to support only smaller speed increases in the order of 1.5 - 2 times.
How can I solve this problem?

You can convert the existing video to time-laps (or more extreme time lapse), with VLC: https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/convert-standard-video-time-lapse/ .

From FFmpeg Wiki: Speeding up/slowing down video:

Speeding up/slowing down video
The speed of a video stream can be changed by changing the presentation timestamp (PTS) of each video frame. This can be done via two methods: using the ​setpts video filter (which requires re-encoding) or by erasing the timestamps by exporting the video to a raw bitstream format and muxing to a container while creating new timestamps.
Note that in the following examples, the audio stream is not changed, so it should ideally be disabled with -an.
raw bitstream method
This method is lossless and apart from changing the timestamps, copies the video stream as-is. Use this if you require no other changes to your input video.
First, copy the video to a raw bitstream format.
For H.264:
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -map 0:v -c:v copy -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb raw.h264

For H.265:
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -map 0:v -c:v copy -bsf:v hevc_mp4toannexb raw.h265

Then generate new timestamps while muxing to a container:
ffmpeg -fflags +genpts -r 30 -i raw.h264 -c:v copy output.mp4

Change the value of -r to the desired playback frame rate.
setpts filter
To double the speed of the video with the setpts filter, you can use:
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -filter:v "setpts=0.5*PTS" output.mkv


The filter works by changing the presentation timestamp (PTS) of each video frame. For example, if there are two succesive frames shown at timestamps 1 and 2, and you want to speed up the video, those timestamps need to become 0.5 and 1, respectively. Thus, we have to multiply them by 0.5.
Note that this method will drop frames to achieve the desired speed. You can avoid dropped frames by specifying a higher output frame rate than the input. For example, to go from an input of 4 FPS to one that is sped up to 4x that (16 FPS):
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -r 16 -filter:v "setpts=0.25*PTS" output.mkv



It might make sense to leave out some frames, as you and/or your monitor can't see/display all of them anyway.
From Speed up a video 30x using only key frames with ffmpeg?:

For a H264/5 stream, this can be done in two steps:
ffmpeg -discard nokey -i t1.mp4 -c copy t1.264

ffmpeg -r 30 -i t1.264 -c copy t1keys.mp4


